# What are the things i need to do before installing windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, backup, drivers, installation

I have a windows XP2 32-bit and i want to install windows 7 but i do not know what are things i should do before installing it. its my fist time to install an OS if ever. I mean, specifically on the drivers, BIOS, and others? how will i know that the drivers are compatible to win7? how to install it on first boot? hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3):

Short list (in no specific order)
- backup your firefox/chrome/opera profile (passwords and such) and mail (if using outlook or some email client)
- backup your data and everything else
- wireless settings to your network, and other such stuff (I like bacuping stuff and then deleting it ... that way I see what's left so I don't forget anything)
- after you're left with an empty disc, go to your Control panel, check out your hardware and search for Win7 drivers online ... download ... burn to disc
- after that, it's no problem really ... you put in the dvd and destroy your current partition (assuming you wish to install 7 over XP) ... here's a nice tutorial of the [inns and outs of it](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-7/514412-windows-7-installation-guide-tutorial.html) - disregard the part about installing it to a virtual machine

Comment: how do i back up those wireless settings and drivers? and how to install on first boot?

Comment: +1 for all the steps. This is pretty much what I did when I upgraded my laptop, and the process was painless as a result.

Comment: @soulchopper - under "wireless settings" I mean mostly passwords to your networks and any other you're commonly accessing - NirSoft's http://www.nirsoft.net/password_recovery_tools.html tools are good in letting you see those. Just write them on paper somewhere. If you're not using any of those, just skip this step. As far as installing on first boot goes, i'm not quite sure what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

> how will i know that the drivers are
>   compatible to win7?

You should download and run the **[Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1B544E90-7659-4BD9-9E51-2497C146AF15&displaylang=en)** to see if your PC is ready for Windows 7. It scans your hardware, devices, and installed programs for known compatibility issues, gives you guidance on how to resolve potential issues found, and recommends what to do before you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has put together [an excellent tutorial](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/upgrading-from-windows-xp-to-windows-7), including a short video, on upgrading from Windows XP to Windows 7.